# How to find out if deque's element has more than two same values

Tags: c++, class, deque

If I have

```
class myElement{
public:
int get_first();
int get_second();
int get_third();
int get_fourth();

private:
deque<int> numbers_ = {1, 2, 3, 4} // numbers are different in every element
};
```

and

```
class myElements{
public:
bool check(); // checks if theres more than two elements that contains the same number
private:
deque<myElement> elements_;
};
```

What would be a good way to find out if elements_ has more than two elements with atleast one same number?

for example: {1, 0, 0, 6} {1, 2, 3, 4} {4, 2, 3, 1} each of those have number 1 so check() would return true.

Comment: If the contents are sorted, you could run [`adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) on the `deque`

Comment: My first thought would be to insert all the numbers in the myElements into a set and check that the insertion succeeded (if it does not succeed, it means the number already exists), but there is probably some more efficient solution than that.

Comment: Keep a count of the number of times you see each number, and if that count for any number is the number of items in the list, then you have a match.

Comment: What is 'a good way'?  Correct?  Efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, a `vector` is a better choice here than a `deque`.  The straightforward way would be to check for each element of the first container if it occurs in all other containers:

The `myElement` 'container-like' class:

```
using namespace std;

class myElement{
public:
    bool contains(int n) const {
      return find(numbers_.begin(), numbers_.end(), n) != numbers_.end();
    }
    myElement(std::vector<int> ns):numbers_(ns){}
    vector<int> values() const { return numbers_; }
private:
    vector<int> numbers_;// = {1, 2, 3, 4} // numbers are different in every element
};
```

The `myElements` extensions:

```
class myElements{
public:
    myElements(initializer_list<myElement>&& t): elements_(t){}
    bool check() {
      myElement& first = elements_.front();

      for ( auto n: first.values()) {
         if (occurs_in_each_but_first(n)) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
    }

private:

    bool occurs_in_each_but_first(int n) {
      auto it = begin(elements_);
      ++it;
      auto itEnd = end(elements_);
      for (; it != itEnd; ++it) {
         if (! it->contains(n)) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    vector<myElement> elements_;
};
```

A test:

```
#include <cassert>
void main(){
  myElement e0({11,12,13,4});
  myElement e1({11,12,13,41});
  myElement e2({1,2,3,4});
  myElement e3({1,2,3,4});
  myElement e4({1,22,23,24});

  assert(myElements({e0,e2,e3}).check());
  assert(!myElements({e1,e2,e3}).check());
  assert(myElements({e2,e3,e4}).check());
}
```

Where optimizations are possible, of course.